# mongodb, what's the `cursor.exec` mean?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I search for hours, but still not found any information about it.

```
var cursor = db.collection('students');
cursor.skip(10).limit(10)

cursor.exec(function(err, result) {...})
```

Is there any `docs` about `exec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` is a helper method of [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/):

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html
- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec

Comment: Yes, I thought `exec` is the `node-mongodb-native` driver method. I found it by `Mongoose` doc.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a query to a MongoDB, you are returned a cursor to an array stored in the server’s memory.

You can think the cursor as a pointer or the reference to array Data
So when you call cursor.next();

Next Array array data is outputted
Whenever you use an aggregation framework each pipeline stage can output max(16 MB) as it is can use only 16MB of RAM space

```
var cursor = db.collection('students');
```

So your answer here cursor is nothing but a pointer to the array or data retrieved and exec nothing but helper method of Mongoose check @str link

Comment: Yes, thanks. I just found the `exec` is a method of mongoose.